# Django Template: Access list element by model attribute

Tags: python, django, templates, model

I have a list of model instances and want to calculate a value for each of it in my view to show it on the page.
I got stuck when I tried to pass this value to the template.

My attempts:
1) Something like `{{ list.(model.pk) }}` - obviously a syntax error. I searched around the web and the documentation but couldn't find a valid syntax to evaluate a specific part of a "dot"-concatenation first.

2) Give the model a non-database attribute and access it simply with `{{ instance.non_db_value }}`. But it seems that the template gets its model values directly from the database, so this also failed.

A somewhat ugly solution might be to wrap all the model instances in the model list into a list of single lists, two values each: the first the instance itself, the second the calculated value I need to pass to the template.
With this, I could access the values with something like this:

```
{% for entry in wrapperlist %}
    {{ wrapperlist.entry.0 }} <-> {{ wrapperlist.entry.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't think this can't be it - am I thinking in the wrong direction? Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: django template filter or tag...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, template doesn't get model values directly from DB. For template processor, your model instance it is yet another object. So, it is totally ok to:

```
#views.py
foo_list = models.Foo.objects.all()

for foo in foo_list:
    foo.non_db_property = some_method()

render_to_response('template.html', {'foo_list': foo_list})
```

and in template:

```
{% for foo in foo_list %}
    <li>{{ foo.non_db_property }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

if it doesn't work for you, check out for errors.

Another approach is to create a model method if value is based on model properties only:

```
#models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    ....
    def non_db_value(self):
         #calculate
         return value
```

template will remain the same as above

Comment: Thanks, I got it - I refactored the code and now the problem is mysteriously gone. The main thing I did was to put all the entries in Model.objects.all() into a second buffer list, as iterating over the variable-saved .all() (list = Model.objects.all()) twice seemed to delete the non-db values. Strange.